# JAXB UnmarshallException unexpected element but "Expected elements are (none)"

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, unmarshalling

I try make a very 'abstract' method to convert any type of Object to an XML-String and vise versa using JAXB (`javax.xml.bind.*`). 
I get a very strange error which I don't know the meaning of.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Incident"). Expected elements are (none)
```

I have searched for numerous solutions on google and stackoverflow, yet their solution don't seem t help. I'm facing a dead end here.

**My converter method**

```
public Object convertXmlToObject(String string, Class c) throws ConversionException {
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(c.getClass());
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            Object converted = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(stream);
            return converted;
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ConversionException("Could not convert the message to an Object", e);
        }
    }
```

**where I call the method**

```
public void generateIncidentReport(Incident incident) throws RepositoryException, ConversionException { 
    ConversionTool conversionTool = new Converter();
    String xmlMessage = conversionTool.convertObjectToXml(incident);
    //...
}
```

**My Incident class**(which has al the needed annotations)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Incident")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Incident {
    @XmlElement(name = "shipId")
    private int shipID;
    @XmlElement(name = "incidentType")
    private String type;
    @XmlElement(name = "action")
    private String action;
    @XmlElement(name = "centraleID")
    private String centraleID;
    @XmlElement(name = "Ship")
    private Ship ship;

    public Incident() {
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

and last **the XML String**

```
<Incident><incidentType>Medisch noodgeval</incidentType><shipId>1234567</shipId></Incident>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(c.getClass());
```

with `c` already being a class, therefore creating a context for `java.lang.Class`. What you need is

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
```

Comment: Goddamn it, how could I have been so blind, this obviously worked.. This is why programming more than 18 hours straight is not a good idea. Lesson well learned, going to grab some coffee.